# require('backbone') returns different object in different files

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, npm, browserify, commonjs

backbone1.js

```
var backbone1=require('backbone');
window.backbone=backbone1;
```

backbone2.js

```
console.log(window.backbone===require('backbone'));
```

Why is the condition returning false. Shouldn't it return the same object everytime?

**Edit:**

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="bundle1.js"></script><!--backbone1.js compiles to bundle1.js"-->
    <script src="bundle2.js"></script><!--backbone2.js compiles to bundle2.js"-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: window.backbone is not undefined, I checked

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use === to compare if two objects are equal. Since you're using backbone, which has underscore as a dependency, you can use [_.isEqual](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) to compare if two objects are equal.